# Excel VBA to join array string to cell content

Tags: vba, excel

Morning All,

Would anyone be able to assist with the following query on Excel VBA code.

I have a macro that creates a new sheet, copies its content and in addition copies a column from the new sheet into a front page summary sheet. Unfortunately the forumla is not copying across with the column.

The new sheet is created and named using "Trim(arr(0))" On this sheet the contents of Column V are then transposed into a "Summary Sheet". Everything copies across Titles, Format but the formula does not.

For example on the new sheet Cell V13 has a formula of +Test_Sheet!Y4/Test_Sheet!Y6 however when it is copied over it comes up with an error

Comment: Can you provide some code? Can you point out, where in the code an issue is?

Comment: Does this help at all?

Comment: With Sheets("Summary Sheet")
        .Columns("H:I").Insert
        .Columns("H:I").Value = Sheets("Dummy_sheet").Range("v:w").Value
        
        
        .Range("h10").Value = Trim(arr(1))
        .Range("h2").Value = Trim(arr(0))
  
        End With
    With Sheets("Dummy_Sheet").Select
    Columns("V:W").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Summary Sheet").Select
    Columns("H:I").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: Please edit you code into the question, use Ctrl + K when all code is highlighted to ensure is in a code box. Indent your code as well so easier to follow flow.

Answer (score 0):

You are only copying the values:

```
 .Columns("H:I").Value = Sheets("Dummy_sheet").Range("v:w").Value
```

You need to copy everything to get the formulas:

```
 Sheets("Dummy_sheet").Range("v:w").copy .Columns("H:I")
```